# Is there any way(intent) to launch Google Now application with search query(String)?

Tags: android, android-intent

i wanna launch Google now app with some string(ex: Dell monitors) with the help of intents. With the following code i am able to launch application, But don't know how to give Search query.

```
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
     if(packageInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("googlequick")) {
            Intent in = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);

                                              if(in!=null)
                                              {
                                                  startActivity(in);
                                              }
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

man, Open APIs of **Google Now** will come into being soon. You can read [this](http://phandroid.com/2015/03/16/google-now-api/). And meanwhile, some apps have integrated with **Google Now**, like [here](http://www.google.com/landing/now/integrations.html).The implementation of Google Now is in the format of **Now Card**s. You can get more information about Google Now Open APIs through Google.
Be optimistic!